# sudo easy_install ipython==1.2.1 erroring out

Tags: python, pip

```
sudo easy_install ipython==1.2.1
```

> Searching for ipython==1.2.1
>
> Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/ipython/
>
> Couldn't find index page for 'ipython' (maybe misspelled?)
>
> Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
>
> Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
>
> No local packages or download links found for ipython==1.2.1
>
> error: Could not find suitable distribution for
>   Requirement.parse('ipython==1.2.1')

Answer (score -2):

**sudo yum install python-ipython**

This resolved the issue.